# How To Put A Threshold Map Over An Image?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, image-thresholding

Hi so I have used a saliency map alongside thresholding to obtain a threshold map of an image. Below is the original, salience map and threshold image respectively:

```
import cv2

imgpath = r'D:\Documents\University\MSc Data Science\Bath\Modules\Programming\Dissertation\Content Image.jpg'
image = cv2.imread(imgpath)

width = 350
height = 450
dim = (width, height)
 
# resize image
resized = cv2.resize(image, dim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)

saliency = cv2.saliency.StaticSaliencyFineGrained_create()
(success, saliencyMap) = saliency.computeSaliency(resized)

# Set threshold for saliency map
ret, threshMap = cv2.threshold((saliencyMap * 255).astype('uint8'), 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
cv2.imshow("Image", resized)
cv2.imshow("Output", saliencyMap)
cv2.imshow("Thresh", threshMap)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

The pictures are below:

[image]
[image]
[image]

The issue I'm having now is, I'm not sure how to put the threshold map over the original image, to get a new image that just has the content of what is in the threshold? Does anyone know what I could do to do this? The resultant image I want is one that copies the threshold image but only the parts of the content image that is white on the threshold map.

Comment: Use the method `copyTo` with a binary version of the threshold output (0, 1 for each value) as the mask https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.2/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a626fe5f96d02525e2604d2ad46dd574f

Comment: If your mask has values 0 and 1, try multiplying it with the image to be masked. You can also use Python fancy indexing.

Comment: "Below is the original, salience map and threshold image respectively".  I do not see any images!